# ZooKeeper: how to correctly reconnect when session expired?

Tags: java, distributed, apache-zookeeper

[ZooKeeper FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ZooKeeper/FAQ) tells that ZooKeeper object must be recreated when state becomes SESSION_EXPIRED.

Are there any examples of code that does such reconnection properly? Recipes folder in zookeeper distro contains two examples of code that both assume that session never expires. This is naïve, because after server gets diconnected from ZooKeeper cluster for 5 minutes, both queue and lock won't work again after connectivity reestablished.

Answer (score 0):

[ZkClient](https://github.com/sgroschupf/zkclient) does that you can look at the code. It also has a listener implementation where you could register a listener implementation and get a persistent notification when the session expires